# unable to upgrade ubuntu 11.04 to ubuntu 11.10

Tags: upgrade

When I tried to upgrade my ubuntu 11.04 to ubuntu 11.10 through update manager's **upgrade** option, after entering password It didn't do aanything after downloading 2 upgrade files. I tried it several times but each time the result is same. So,please tell me how can I upgrade to 11.10 or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

Try  *`**sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**`* in the terminal.

Comment: I think you should remove the `*` from the command for less confusion. Putting the command as a `<code>` is enough in my opinion.